# Flash overlapping ModalPopupExtender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, flash, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am facing the problem in showing AJAX Control Toolkit `ModalPopupExtender` over Flash.  When popup comes out, it will overlap by flash (it's giving me problem in IE 8, it's working fine in Firefox).

Can anybody tell me how I will get out of this?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether flash  tag has a parameter "wmode" set to "transparent". If this parameter is missing, add the parameter.

Comment: thanks for reply but i have done that and still getting problem in IE8

Comment: What is the z-index of the overlay/modal window and the flash container?

Comment: z index for the flash container is 0 and for the Modal its 90

Answer (score 0):

Add a `wmode transparent` param to your Flash. Without know more about how you’re embedding your Flash it’s difficult to give precise code.

Comment: thanks for reply but I have done this but still getting problem in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to set "wmode" as "opaque" (don't use "transparent" unless you really need it!) in both embed and object tags.

See more info here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html

But be sure what to use it for and that you really need it. Check out this Tinic Uro post: http://www.kaourantin.net/2010/02/core-animation.html